# Proper method of mixing xml layouts with Views

Tags: android, android-layout

Android newbie question here.  I've got an app that I'm experimenting with that the bulk of the screen is handled nicely with basic XML-defined objects.  I want to use just one portion of the screen for drawing some graphics.

While I can allocate the proper area to a View or SurfaceView, the code examples I find for those use setContentView() and the graphics section is rendered over the entire screen.  What am I missing???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create custom view for rengering your graphics and put it in some layout in your xml layout file together with other stuf you want on screen. Then use this layout in setContentView.